# pthreads join - How to cancel the join for another thread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

i want to be able to switch the target tread to join to.
Say t1 waits for t2. t2 didn't exit yet but now i want t1 to wait for t3 instead.
Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want the non-portable [`pthread_timedjoin_np`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_tryjoin_np.3.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make t1 wait for t3 as there is no way to interrupt pthread_join whilst keeping it running, however you can cancel t1 with pthread_cancel which will terminate it and thus you will no longer be waiting for t2 to finish, and get a different thread to wait for t3.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not possible. But you may follow the advice in `pthread_join()` description.

> The pthread_join() function is a
>   convenience that has proven useful in
>   multi-threaded applications. It is
>   true that a programmer could simulate
>   this function if it were not provided
>   by passing extra state as part of the
>   argument to the start_routine(). The
>   terminating thread would set a flag to
>   indicate termination and broadcast a
>   condition that is part of that state;
>   a joining thread would wait on that
>   condition variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a condition variable between t1 and t2.then you could join t3 to t1.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to emulate `pthread_timedjoin_np` portably:

1. Create a new thread to perform the `pthread_join`, and pass it a condition variable or semaphore.
2. Perform a timed wait on the condition variable or semaphore.
3. Call `pthread_cancel` on the new thread.
4. Call `pthread_join` on the new thread.

Of course I've left some details out, but they're easy to fill in.